# UITableViewCell initialisation with initwithstyle method

Tags: uitableview

Can anyone explain me what is happening here while initialising UITableViewCell .Thanks in advance

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nibArray=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        self=[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the nib array from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object 
        cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
   //set cell data
```

```
return cell;
```

}